How to find the matrix of L with respect to the standard basis of $M_2$
The function L:$M_2$ $\rightarrow$ $M_2$ given by L(X)= AX-XA where
A =  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$
I've already calculated that L$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -2 \\ 3 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ , L$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} -3 & -3 \\ 0 & 3 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$, L$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 3 & -2 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$, and L$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ -3 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$
I'm not sure as to how to use these matrices to create a single matrix w.r.t $M_2$. Did I go wrong somewhere?

If you think a linear operator defined on matrix space is too abstract, then try to consider $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ as $\mathbb{R}^4$ (via the natural isomorphism). Then brute-force expansion on $AX-XA$ would give you a linear map of $x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22}$, then it may be easier to idenfity the matrix representation in this case.

Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$, where
$$
e_1=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right), \quad
e_2=\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right), \quad
e_3=\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right), \quad
e_4=\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right), \tag{1}
$$
be the standard basis of $M_2$. The results of your calculations can be rewritten as
$$\begin{cases}
Le_1=-2e_2+3e_3, \\
Le_2=-3e_1-3e_2+3e_4, \\ 
Le_3=2e_1+3e_3-2e_4, \\ 
Le_4=2e_2-3e_3. 
\end{cases} \tag{2}
$$
Therefore, the matrix representation of $L$ in the standard basis of $M_2$ is
$$
L=\left(\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & -3 & 2 & 0 \\ -2 & -3 & 0 & 2 \\ 3 & 0 & 3 & -3 \\ 0 & 3 & -2 & 0 \end{array}\right). \tag{3}
$$
